# Initial Handlebars.js None Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm trying to learn Handlebars.js (first hour) & seem to be hitting an initial problem (it isn't working).

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hi!</p>
    <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Real Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#users}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{username}}</td>
                    <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{email}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/users}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("I'm Here!");
    var source = $("#some-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var data = {
        users: [{
            username: "alan",
            firstName: "Alan",
            lastName: "Johnson",
            email: "alan@test.com"
        }, {
            username: "allison",
            firstName: "Allison",
            lastName: "House",
            email: "allison@test.com"
        }, {
            username: "ryan",
            firstName: "Ryan",
            lastName: "Carson",
            email: "ryan@test.com"
        }]
    };
    $("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));
});
```

I'm seeing the console log, but the table is not being written at all.  There are no console error messages & I'm a bit stuck as to where the snag is.

Hopefully it is not tiredness causing something obvious like a typo...

Comment: I don't see `#content-placeholder` anywhere in your page.  If that's the case, then `$("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));` does not do anything.

Comment: I was using this guide - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-with-handlebars-js there is obviously a typo in the guide.  I've answered the question with the alterations to make the code work.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It appears that the guide just assumes you realize that you need to have a `<div id="content-placeholder"></div>` in your document to be the target for `$("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));`.  I wouldn't personally call it a typo, but rather they just didn't show the whole HTML document that is needed to make their sample work (more of an omission rather than a typo).  In any case, glad you got it figured out.

Comment: it would be nice if jQuery had an option to warn/throw on selector misses instead of covering up the fact that something you told it to do could not be accomplished...

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 - I'm slightly confused as to where you would wrap the div - would you give a code example as to how it should be done? Thanks

Comment: @MrT - I don't know what you mean by "wrap the div".  I posted an answer yesterday that shows how you fix it by just defining the content-placeholder div in your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code work as you have it, you need to define an HTML element in your document that matches `#content-placeholder` so that `$("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));` has a place to put the rendered template.

You could solve that by adding it to your HTML like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hi!</p>
    <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Real Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#users}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{username}}</td>
                    <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{email}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/users}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>

    <!-- Add this line -->
    <div id="content-placeholder"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was expecting this not to work as the table was outside of this.  Hows that work?!

Comment: @MrT - I'm not sure what you're asking.  The table is in the template and is referred to by the template's id `"some-template"`.  The `"content-placeholder"` div is just a place in your page to insert content with `$("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));`.  You can put it anywhere in the document (except not inside the template).

Comment: Ah. OK.  That makes sense.  As long as its in there, it'll find the relevant {{xyz}}?

Comment: @MrT - Well `$('some selector')` searches the entire document for one or more tags that match whatever selector you specify - that's how jQuery works.  So, the matching tags can be anywhere in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

`$("#content-placeholder").html(template(data));`

to

`$('body').append(template(data));`

& I got the desired output.